# What's the select2 v4 equivalent of v3.5's nextSearchTerm?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2-4, jquery-select2

[Select2](http://select2.github.io/) used to have an option for `nextSearchTerm` which you could use to prepopulate the search field with their last search...

e.g.

```
$('#customer_id').select2({
    nextSearchTerm: function(selectedObject, currentSearchTerm) {
        return currentSearchTerm;
    },
```

How can I implement that same functionality in v4, since the method seems to be missing?